# Can you sign in to a website using you Twitter handle?

Tags: android, twitter, signing

I am trying to create an android application and would like the users of the application to sign in themselves using their twitter accounts / usernames / handles.

I could accomplish these things using the **facebook** and **google+** frameworks / apis. Is it also possible to do it using twitter?

Moreover, I wish to create a chat plugin with possible either signed using their facebook / google / twitter / microsoft account or through a form login. Can I use the twitter handle once the user has signed in to comment and like on the website.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You have to use Fabric from Twitter.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/access-rest-api.html